# How to get contains value in dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery

```
var State = "State";
$("#StateOrigin option:contains(" + State + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

In above line, not support for getting Uppercase and lower. I need to get whatever case.

Answer (score 0):

`:contains` must be exact case, you can use `filter(function)` instead

```
var State = "State";
$("#StateOrigin option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === State.toLowerCase();
}).prop('selected', true);
```

This assumes that you are indeed looking for option text and not `value` of options.

If you are looking for `value` you can switch `val()` for `text()` in above code

Answer (score 0):

```
var State = "State";
$("#StateOrigin option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === State.toLowerCase();
}).prop('selected', true);
```